# ag-grid how to remove the sum prefix for an aggregation func

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I have the sum function but I don't want the word 'sum' label to be part of the prefix of the column name.

[image]

Here is an example from the documentation showing the sum and a Plurk to play around with the code.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/aggregation/

I would appreciate if anybody knows how to remove that prefix from the column name thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did this by setting the property `suppressaggfuncinheader` to true in our Layout.

https://docs.adaptabletools.com/reference/layout#suppressaggfuncinheader